# How I can understand which direction I drag in touch event?

Tags: android, touch

I mean I want to understand the user drag his finger on screen which direction?
How can I use touch event?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just Go through this Example. A Toast will display when your Swiping on the Screen..

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938657/1298796)

Comment: Remember to read the last comment in the example since the original answer is quite old.

Comment: thanks for answering. But  it doesnt enter onfling method ever. Why it doesnt enter

Comment: Have you seen the whole example.

Comment: It should i just checked the developer's site http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener%28%29

Comment: I have a class extends view class. When I touch screen touch method of my view class is work but does not work onfling method